# Error with JPA request

Tags: java, jpa

I have a EJBQL request that generate an error:

**EJBQL request:**

```
javax.persistence.Query multipleSelect= em.createQuery("SELECT p.pname,j.descriptor from Project p LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodeassociation n  ON p.id=n.sourceNodeId and n.sinkNodeEntity='WorkflowScheme' LEFT OUTER JOIN Workflowscheme w  ON n.sourceNodeId = w.id LEFT OUTER JOIN Jiraworkflows j ON w.name=j.workflowname; " );
```

**Error:**

```
line 1:244 mismatched character ' ' expecting set ''..''
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT p.pname,j.descriptor   from Project p LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodeassociation n  ON p.id=n.sourceNodeId and n.sinkNodeEntity='WorkflowScheme' LEFT OUTER JOIN Workflowscheme w  ON n.sourceNodeId = w.id LEFT OUTER JOIN Jiraworkflows j ON w.name=j.workflowname; ].
 Internal Exception:   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException
```

**UPDATE**
After removing semicolone:

```
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT p.pname,j.descriptor   from Project p LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodeassociation n  ON p.id=n.sourceNodeId and n.sinkNodeEntity='WorkflowScheme' LEFT OUTER JOIN Workflowscheme w  ON n.sourceNodeId = w.id LEFT OUTER JOIN Jiraworkflows j ON w.name=j.workflowname ].
Internal Exception:     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException
```

**UPDATE:**

```
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT p.pname,j.descriptor from Project p LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodeassociation n  ON p.id=n.sourceNodeId  n.sinkNodeEntity='WorkflowScheme' LEFT OUTER JOIN Workflowscheme w  ON n.sourceNodeId = w.id LEFT OUTER JOIN Jiraworkflows j ON w.name=j.workflowname ].
Internal Exception:  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException
```

Comment: I never used and saw a semicolon in an EJB query. Can you try after removing semicolon?

Comment: @Asad Rasheed ,still not working

Comment: Please can you post the full stack trace.

Comment: @Asad Rasheed, I have updated my post

Comment: Can you try this: **SELECT p from Project p LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodeassociation n  ON p.id=n.sourceNodeId LEFT OUTER JOIN Workflowscheme w  ON n.sourceNodeId = w.id LEFT OUTER JOIN Jiraworkflows j ON w.name=j.workflowname where n.sinkNodeEntity='WorkflowScheme'**

Comment: @Asad Rasheed,still not working ,I have tried so many possibility but in vain :(

Comment: can you please paste the complete stack trace.